# Blender 2.81 missing pie menu

Tags: add-on, pie-menu

Yesterday I switched to 2.81 stable and now all Pie menus appear as usual except when I press Tab, then it only switches from edit to object mode and back, as if there is no pie menu add on installed. 
If anyone has a solution to this I'd love to hear it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to check "Tab for Pie Menu" box in Preferences>Keymap

[image: Tab for pie menu]

Comment: Thank you a lot! Though this does not apply for 2.7X controls.